Can an already compiled binary recompiled for another architecture?
Let's say we have an ARM binary and we want to run this in x86 device, underlying operating system (in this case it's Ubuntu) is same.
The idea in this case would be:

Disassemble the binary

Rewrite the binary to have x86 instructions instead of ARM instructions while handling all the potential differences between instruction sets.

In end everything should be calling syscalls to the OS itself or importing the standard library.


This is probably isn't that straightforward since there are a lot of differences in.
But in theory would such approach be possible / feasible at all? If such thing can be done it would be probably called something like "Ahead of time emulation" giving very high performance in the result of binary. Normally an emulator would take all the instructions and simulate the cpu entirely but in this case instead of simulating a cpu it'll just convert them as it is in directly binary form without executing.
AFAIK this is currently done not in binary form directly and for virtual assemblies like MSIL or Java Bytecode even then you can't simply take a IL executable made from C# source code and turn it into x86 it has to be done in original compilation step.
What would be steps need to be taken to write a good "ahead of time emulation" system? What could be major challenges in such attempt. How feasible it is? What about potential optimizations

"What would be steps need to be taken to write a good... - I'd translate the assembly into the format LLVM wants and then use that to re-optimize it for the target platform.

... but this question is too broad for SO in its current shape i.m.o.

Yes, it's feasible, and yes it's been done, at least sort of.
In the 1990's, Microsoft ported Windows to run on DEC Alpha based machines. But most Windows programs were compiled for the x86, not Alpha. So, DEC created a binary re-compiler much like you're describing that basically took x86 code as input and emitted Alpha code as output.
It was written as a JIT style compiler, so it ran as the program was running, but cached the output code, so if you had something like a loop, it didn't need to re-translate the code in the loop every iteration. If I recall correctly, the resulting binary code was also saved long term, so subsequent executions didn't necessarily involve any translation at all (but this was 25+ years ago and my personal contact with it was pretty minimal, so I don't recall a lot of details with any certainty).
It was, however, a commercial, closed-source product so details are hard to find. If you search for "FX!32", you can probably turn up at least a little more though (if nothing else, at least confirmation that it worked, and was efficient enough that for a while it was the fastest way to run quite a few Windows programs).
